# Python Web-Scraping Daily + Email?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a json link to a website that I would like to scrape once daily and then have the contents of that emailed to me. I already have the entire scraping portion of code set up. Just not sure how to automate that kind of thing and then send it off.

Mac system using vscode.

Comment: I think using [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or some other system scheduler (no idea on Windows, sorry) will allow you to run a script daily. Just wrap your python script with a command line script to kick it off, and run that  script with the cron job and you're good to go. 
 EDIT: Vscode doesn't matter, that's just your IDE. If you're on a Mac, you can use cron jobs since they are unix! Look up a tutorial, they are super cool!

Comment: You could also user a combination of Python Celery and rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

In a mac system exists cronjobs.

Open up your terminal and type

```
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

Add the following which will run at midnight

```
0 0 * * * /your/path/to/python scrape.py
```

Ctrl+O then Ctrl+X to save and exit.

That's it.

You did not specify if your script already emails as well. You can add MAILTO="" at the top of your cronjob edit to send wherever.

And finally, you might get weird 'command not found' errors even thought your script works. If that's the case, add

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

to the top of your script.